# Algorithm to determine order of words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, pattern-matching, string-matching

I want to check the order of words between the database value and the user input.

ex:

> Example one:
>
> DB value: Lorem Ipsum
>
> User Input: Ipsum Lorem
>
> Example 2:
>
> DB value: Lorem Ipsum Dolo
>
> User Input: Dolo Lorem Ipsum  (and possible combinations apart from
>   the exact db value)

I would have done a split on whitespace and compared indices of matching words but there is always a chance of a misspell with that. Ex:

> DB value: Lorem Ipsum
>
> User input : Lorm Ipsm

In my application I have to allow tolerance for some misspell. Is there a way to check the order in any other way?

I am currently working with Levenshtein in the following way (Ruby on Rails code)

```
answer = 'Lorem Ipsum'

response = 'Ipsum Lorem'

score = Text::Levenshtein.distance(answer,response)/answer.length.to_f
```

Is this the right way to score using levenshtein? If yes how do I determine acceptable score? Any sample data resource on the same? For this particular example above I get the score as `0.72`

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve? Are you matching user input to db records regardless of order and allowing for misspelling?

Comment: Not matching but getting some sort of score in the variation of word order in user input compared to the db record. This while allowing for misspelling.

Comment: Based on the score of this variation I will choose to either consider it as correct input or incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

So you have 2 problems to solve:

1. Check for arrangements of words
2. Add wiggle room for spelling errors

Both can be solved by using Levenshtein Distance algorithm, but with a twist:

1. You are looking at Fuzzy searching or Approximate String Matching. There are many algorithms out there, but from top of my head, [Damerau-Levenshtein Distance Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance) or [Bitap Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitap_algorithm). They both are based on Levenshtein. You may search for better algorithm for your application.
2. Spelling errors - Levenshtein distance is probably easier to implement and use; and may be efficient too.

HTH

Edit: The first thing I would solve is implementing `Levenshtein distance` on individual words. Since, we are not really aware of what you mean by DB here (could be simple text file containing your sentences or an actual DBMS like `MySQL`), assuming it to be a DBMS, I will create a dictionary of all words appeared in all sentences. Following which I will write a `Stored Procedure` implementing `Levenshtein distance`. Passing the array of words of testing sentence and apply the stored procedure on all words. Then replace the words in DB sentences as well as your testing sentence with the ID of the most aligned word.

E.g. In DB, you have a sentence 'Lorem Ipsum', and keeping a table of words we will have a table named 'words' with 2 records:

```
|---------------------|
| id | words          |
|---------------------|
|  1 | Lorem          |
|  2 | Ipsum          |
|---------------------|
```

Create a `Stored Procedure` implementing `Levenshtein Distance` and pass the array of testing sentence (user input) say `[Ipsum, Lorem]`.

You would get atleast one aligned word for each word of user input. Replace them with consecutive `id` from table `words`. In our example, returning array will probably look like `[2,1]`.

This solves the second problem of spelling errors.

For Fuzzy searching, get one record (sentence) from DB, replace the words with `id` from table `words` (you already have an array of ids returned from previous stored procedure) and apply any algorithm like `Damerau-Levenshtein Distance Algorithm`, `Bitap Algorithm`, `Smith-Waterman Algorithm`, `Needleman-Wunsch Algorithm`. In fact, I would suggest you to implement 2-3 of them and compare which works better in your case.

HTH

Comment: Already using levenshtein.But on the entire string. Updating the question with code.

Comment: Levenshtein on entire string seems to be unnecessary in your case, and will definitely slows down entire system if strings are too big. What I meant was that you would need to create a structure in a way that combines Levenshtein distance on words and Fuzzy search algorithm on words effectively and efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be solved by splitting both the user input and the db records into an array of words, then computing the levenshtein distance for each pair. Then you need to work out which set of pairings minimizes the score.

Each set of words in the user input would then be matched with a word in the db record, so you can then calculate a score based on whether they are in the same position or not